# Insert <br> into paragraph via javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So here is the code that matters that I have:

```
// app.js
$scope.buy = function(name, price) {
console.log(name, price);
$scope.cart[0].subtotal = $scope.cart[0].subtotal + price;
$scope.cart[0].items = $scope.cart[0].items + name + "\n"; // I tried using \n.
}


// index.html
<body ng-controller="StoreController">
<p>Search:</p><input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<input type="radio" name="order" ng-value="true" ng-model="reverse">$$$ - $</input>
<input type="radio" name="order" ng-value="false" ng-model="reverse">$ - $$$</input>
<hr>
<div ng-repeat="items in items | filter:search |orderBy:'price':reverse">
<img id="thumbnail" ng-src="{{ items.thumb }}" />
<h2>{{ items.name }}</h2>
<p>{{ items.price | currency}} </p>
<p>{{ items.desc }} </p>
<button ng-show="items.instock" ng-click="buy(items.name, items.price)">Buy {{items.name}}</button>
<p id="notStocked" ng-hide="items.instock">{{items.name}} is not in stock</p>
<hr>
</div>
<h1>Total Cart Price: {{ cart[0].subtotal }} </h1>
<p id="cartitems">Cart Items: {{ cart[0].items }}</p>
<button ng-show="subtotal > 0">Checkout</button>
</body>
```

I want to use the buy() function to insert a line break in the cartitems paragraph, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Don't try to modify the template using the JavaScript. Modify the template directly. That's the point of having the template.

Comment: @Quentin I don't have a template?

Comment: Your index.html is a template.

Comment: @Quentin well just adding a <br> at the end of the statement won't help, it has to add it when the function is triggered.

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML ?

Comment: In your `ng-repeat` you are doing `items in items`. At best, it makes your code confusing. At worse, it can causes scope issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push the names to an array. Then use `ng-repeat` on a `<span>` tag.

JS

```
$scope.cart[0].purchases = [];
$scope.buy = function(name, price) {
    $scope.cart[0].subtotal += price;
    $scope.cart[0].purchases.push(name);
};
```

HTML

```
<h1>Total Cart Price: {{ cart[0].subtotal }} </h1>
<p id="cartitems">Cart Items: 
    <span ng-repeat="name in cart[0].purchases track by $index">
        {{name}}<br>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I want it to do a breakline everytime you use the function. This will only do it the first time it's been purchased.

Comment: @user2122062 See new answer.

Comment: that seems like it would work, but it just displays what you purchase the first time and then doesn't add anymore after that.

Comment: @user2122062 I added `track by $index`